# Arrays out of bounds exception error java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

so I am a beginner in java. I am trying to create a program that tells me the even ints in the array. However, I keep getting the array out of bounds error:10 at line 29(where I sy "formula[even[b]]. Help please?

```
public class arrayone
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        /* 
    tell me the number of even ints in the given array. Note: the % "mod" operator computes the remainder, e.g. 5 % 2 is 1.
    */

    //declare an array
    int[] even= new int[10];

    //int b is for the forloop so that every number can be added
    int b;

    //

    //initialize the scanner, and enter prompt
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    //enter prompt
    System.out.printf("Enter 10 random numbers\n");

    //make a forloop so every number they put in will be added to the array
    for(b=0;b<10;b++)
    {
    even[b]=input.nextInt();
    }

//then run the formula
formula(even[b]);
    }

    public static void formula(int a)
    {


        //use an if statement to see if the numbers in the array are odd or even.
        for(a=0;a<=10;a++)
        {
        if((a%2)==0)
        {
            System.out.printf("This number is even\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("This number isn't even\n");

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should not be a `for` loop at all in `formula`. You are only expecting an `int`

Comment: I am honestly lost at what you think you are doing. Your `formula` makes no sense at all

Comment: Instead of sending each integer to formula why not just send the whole array like so? https://repl.it/Eu6c/1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's start from the beginning

You read a bunch of inputs and store it in an array, so far so good.

Then you are trying to send only one value to the function `formula` by doing `formula(even[b])`. However, as @Sanjeev pointed out, your `b = 10` at this moment because of the `for` loop just before, hence giving you `array out of bounds`.

And then in `formula` you are only expecting an `int`, but you take this `int` (`a` in your case) and just reassign it in the `for` loop which btw checks what numbers between 0 and 10 (inclusive) are even. Not what you wanted I think.

What you really want to do is either:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    formula(even[i]);
} 

public static void formula(int a)
{
    if((a%2)==0)
    {
        System.out.printf("This number is even\n");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.printf("This number isn't even\n");
    }
}
```

or

```
formula(even);

public static void formula(int[] a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if((a[i]%2)==0)
        {
            System.out.printf("This number is even\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("This number isn't even\n");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: How did you answer the question after it was marked duplicate?

Comment: I think perhaps I was already working on the answer when it was being flagged

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(b=0;b<10;b++)
    {
       even[b]=input.nextInt();
    }
```

After exiting the for-loop value of `b` will be `10` which is more than the capacity of your array `even`. Array indexes are 0-9. Hence the exception.